# White screen flashing on iOS Cordova app

Tags: ios, cordova

I created a HelloWorld app with Cordova:

```
cordova create hello ; cd hello ; cordova platform add ios
```

When I run it on iOS, a white blank screen flashes just before the app is loaded.
How can I get rid of this flashing?

I found many solutions with splash screen configuration, but I don't want a splash screen in my app. (The HelloWorld already has a splash screen, but this does not prevent the flashing problem.)
I also tried to set the background-color to black with no success.

Comment: This link would fix your flashing problem https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of this, the only solution I found was to install the splashscreen plugin and create a black screen image. I also set the preference TopActivityIndicator to whiteLarge. Too bad that Cordova does not work better out of the box.